# showing that $\int_{0}^{1}f^{2}=0$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis

Let $f\in C^{0}\left [ 0,1 \right ]$ such that $\int_{0}^{1}f(x)x^{n}dx=0$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$ show that $\int_{0}^{1}f^{2}=0$ and finally that $f\equiv 0$

the only thing i can get is,  $f$ and $x^{n}$ are continuos in the compact then they are uniformly continuos then, $f(x)x^{n}$ is uniformly continuos then you can approximated by polynomials and we know that the integral is linear so we can get that each coefficient of the approximation is zero... am i on the right way?? 
thanks for any help

Answer (score 7):

Note that you don't need *uniform* continuity, merely continuity (of course, these are equivalent since $[0,1]$ is compact) of $f$ on $[0,1]$ to apply Weiertrass' approximation theorem.

You are on the right way. Approximate $f$ by a polynomial $p$ uniformly over $[0,1]$, so that $$\lVert f-p\rVert_\infty<\varepsilon$$

Since $p$ is a polynomial, $\displaystyle \int_0^1fp=0$, so $$\int_0^1 f^2=\int_0^1f^2-\int_0^1fp=\int_0^1f(f-p)$$

whence $$\left|\int_0^1f^2\right|\leqslant M\varepsilon$$ for every $\varepsilon >0$ where $M$ is an upper bound for $f$ over $[0,1]$. Since $f^2$ is continuous and nonnegative over $[0,1]$ and $\displaystyle \int_0^1f^2=0$, you can conclude $f^2\equiv 0$.